# Why I was not getting the complete dependency

Tags: stanford-nlp

I tried both the online demo and download version of the dependency parser. The online demo's Enhanced Dependencies was able to get accurate results. For example, "Can you recommend me a movie which was directed by James Cameron and Leonardo DiCaprio?" generated below results:

root ( ROOT-0 , recommend-3 )
aux ( recommend-3 , Can-1 )
nsubj ( recommend-3 , you-2 )
nsubj ( movie-6 , me-4 )
det ( movie-6 , a-5 )
xcomp ( recommend-3 , movie-6 )
nsubjpass ( directed-9 , which-7 )
nsubjpass ( acted-14 , which-7 ) (extra)
auxpass ( directed-9 , was-8 )
acl:relcl ( movie-6 , directed-9 )
case ( Cameron-12 , by-10 )
compound ( Cameron-12 , James-11 )
nmod:agent ( directed-9 , Cameron-12 )
cc ( directed-9 , and-13 )
acl:relcl ( movie-6 , acted-14 ) (extra)
conj:and ( directed-9 , acted-14 )
case ( DiCaprio-17 , by-15 )
compound ( DiCaprio-17 , Leonardo-16 )
nmod:by ( acted-14 , DiCaprio-17 )

Although the two verb "directed" and "acted" were separated by a few words, the online demo was able to recognize that they were both referring to the noun "movie" (acl:relcl ( movie-6 , directed-9 ), acl:relcl ( movie-6 , acted-14 ) (extra)).

However, below is the result I got with the jar files downloaded from Stanford's website. The CoreNLP version is 3.6.0:

root(ROOT-0, recommend-3)
aux(recommend-3, Can-1)
nsubj(recommend-3, you-2)
nsubj(movie-7, me-4)
det(movie-7, a-5)
amod(movie-7, romantic-6)
dobj(recommend-3, movie-7)
nsubjpass(directed-10, movie-7)
ref(movie-7, which-8)
auxpass(directed-10, was-9)
acl:relcl(movie-7, directed-10)
case(Cameron-13, by-11)
compound(Cameron-13, James-12)
nmod:agent(directed-10, Cameron-13)
cc(Cameron-13, and-14)
nmod:agent(directed-10, acted-15)
conj:and(Cameron-13, acted-15)
case(DiCaprio-18, by-16)
compound(DiCaprio-18, Leonardo-17)
nmod:by(acted-15, DiCaprio-18)
punct(recommend-3, ?-19)

And in this case, the parser failed to get the dependency acl:relcl ( movie-6 , acted-14 ) (extra).

This is my constructor code:

```
public CoreNlpParser() {
        props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, lemma, depparse, ner");
        props.setProperty("depparse.extradependencies", "MAXIMAL");
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    }
```

I thought that by setting "depparse.extradependencies" to "MAXIMAL" I should be able to
get the same results as the online demo's. What I was missing and how should I properly configure
the annotators? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should more closely match the online demo.  You want to use the PCFG parser, not the NN dependency parser.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.zip.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class EnhancedDependenciesDemo {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        Annotation ann = new Annotation("Can you recommend me a movie " +
                "which was directed by James Cameron and acted by Leonardo DiCaprio?");
        pipeline.annotate(ann);
        for (CoreMap sentence : ann.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
            TreePrint treePrint = new TreePrint("typedDependenciesCollapsed");
            treePrint.printTree(tree);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me what are the differences between them?

Comment: The demo runs the constituency parser and produces dependencies by converting the constituency parse.  The NN dependency parser only creates dependency parses.